# Use helper modules for repeated, ordered tasks when functional testing in intern

Tags: javascript, functional-testing, intern

I'm trying to create a module that will fill in form inputs when functional testing, and I'd like to be able to call it from multiple test suites.

Pseudo code for the helper file (helper.js)

```
module.exports = {
    fillForm: function() {
        this.findByCssSelector('#firstname')
            .click()
            .pressKeys('John')
            .end()
    },
    anotherFunction: function() {
        // more code
    }
}
```

In the spec for the functional test, I load that module as `helper` and I can see it execute. However, it seems I can't use this syntax and guarantee that the chained steps execute in the defined order:

```
'Test filling form data': function() {
    return this.remote
                .get(require(toUrl(url))
                // should happen first
                .then(helper.fillForm)
                // should happen second
                .then(helper.anotherFunction)
                // only after the above should the click happen
                .findByCsSelector('#submit')
                 // click evt should show the #someElement element
                .click()                     
                .findByCssSelector('#someElement')
                .getComputedStyle('display')
                .then(style) {
                     // assertions here
    }
```

It seems that the promise chaining allows the `click` event to happen before the `then` callbacks have executed. Is this sort of flow possible with intern?

UPDATE:

For the moment, working around this with this sort of code:

```
var remote = initTest.call(this, url);
return helpers.fillForm1Data.call(remote)
    .otherChainedMethodsHere()
    .moreChainedMethods()
.then() {
    // assertion code here
```

where the initTest method does url fetching, window sizing, clearing data, and the fillForm1Data does as you'd expect. But the syntax is pretty ugly this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your helper is not `return`ing any value so it is treated as a synchronous callback and the next thing in the chain is executed immediately. You also cannot `return this` from a promise helper or it will cause a deadlock (because the Command promise will be waiting for itself to resolve—Intern will throw an error instead if you try to do this), so you need to create a new Command and return that if you want to use the chained Command interface within your helper:

```js
module.exports = {
    fillForm: function() {
        return new this.constructor(this.session)
            .findByCssSelector('#firstname')
            .click()
            .pressKeys('John');
    },
    anotherFunction: function() {
        // more code
    }
};
```

You can also just return from `this.session` instead if you don’t care about the convenience of the Command API and can deal with normal promise callback chains:

```js
module.exports = {
    fillForm: function() {
        var session = this.session;
        return session.findByCssSelector('#firstname')
          .then(function (element) {
            return element.click();
          })
          .then(function () {
            return session.pressKeys('John');
          });
    },
    anotherFunction: function() {
        // more code
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Colin. I'm able to get things working using the second syntax above. I suspect I can't use the first because the initial get of the url is not creating a promise (using `this.remote.get(require.toUrl(get))`, and the `Command` property of `_promise` is coming back undefined, so `this.constructor(this.session)` is always undefined. I'll post a gist tomorrow of my code for a better explanation.

Comment: It was supposed to be `return new this.constructor`, not `return this.constructor`. I updated the answer.