# Calling functions located in separate files with Intern

Tags: require, intern

Using intern, I have the following directory structure:

```
/intern
  /tests
    globals.js
    pageElements.js
    /functional
      /site1
        site1test1.js
      /site2
        site2test1.js
      /page_objects
        loginPage.js
```

What I want to do is store common functions in the page_objects directory for various pages, such as loginPage.js, and call these functions in the actual tests like site1test1.js etc.  I've tried many various approaches, the latest of which is based on a solution posted here: [Use helper modules for repeated, ordered tasks when functional testing in intern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509966/use-helper-modules-for-repeated-ordered-tasks-when-functional-testing-in-intern).  With this approach I'm seeing "TypeError: Object # has no method 'setFindTimeout'".  I'm very new to intern, and quite new to node.js, so please pardon my ignorance.  I just would like to get input on the best approach to take here.

site1test1.js looks like this:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    'intern',
    'intern/dojo/node!../globals.js',
    'intern/dojo/node!./page_objects/loginPage.js'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require, intern, globals, loginPage) {

    registerSuite({
        name: 'index',

        'login': function () { 

            var current_env = intern.config.environment;
            var user = globals.getData(current_env).USER1;
            var url = globals.getData(current_env).url;

            return this.remote
                .get(url)
                .then(loginPage.login(user, globals.PASSWORD));

        }
    });
});
```

My loginPage.js currently looks like this:

```
var pageElements = require('../../pageElements');
var globals = require('../../globals')

module.exports = {
    login: function(email, password) {
        return new this.constructor(this.session)
            .setFindTimeout(globals.TIMEOUT)
            .findById(pageElements.TEXTFIELD_ID_EMAIL)
            .click()
            .clearValue()
            .type(email)
            .end()
            .findById(pageElements.TEXTFIELD_ID_PASSWORD)
            .click()
            .clearValue()
            .type(password)
            .end()
            .findById(pageElements.BUTTON_ID_LOGIN)
            .click()
            .end()
    }
};
```

Comment: I was able to resolve this by AMDifying the loginPage module as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by AMDifying the loginPage module as follows:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    'intern',
    '../../globals.js',
    '../../pageElements.js'
], function (loginPage,
             assert,
             require,
             intern,
             globals,
             pageElements) {

    var loginPage = {

        login : function (email, password) {

            return this
                .setFindTimeout(globals.TIMEOUT)
                .findById(pageElements.TEXTFIELD_ID_EMAIL).click()
                .clearValue()
                .type(email)
                .end()
                .findById(pageElements.TEXTFIELD_ID_PASSWORD).click()
                .clearValue()
                .type(password)
                .end()
                .findById(pageElements.BUTTON_ID_LOGIN).click()
                .end()
        }

    };
    return loginPage;

});
```

I then can call this in site1test1.js as follows:

```
return this.remote
           .get(url)
           .then(function(){ return loginPage.login.call(this, user, globals.PASSWORD); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work as follows. (based on tera_incognita's answer)

site1test1.js:

```
define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/Command',
  'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/lib/util',
  'require',
  'intern',
  '../page_objects/loginPage.js'
], function (registerSuite, assert, Command, util, require, intern, loginPage) {

registerSuite({
    name: 'index',

    'login': function () {
        var session = this.remote;
        var command = new Command(session);
        var current_env = intern.config.environment;
        var user = 'john_appleseed@apple.com';
        var url = 'http://localhost/hello.html';
        return command
           .get(url)
           .then(function(){ return loginPage.login(session, user, 'password1');});
    }
});
});
```

loginPage.js:

```
define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'require',
  'intern'      
], function (loginPage,
         assert,
         require,
         intern) {

var loginPage = {

    login : function (session, email, password) {

        return session
            .findById('email').click()
            .clearValue()
            .type(email)
            .end()
            .findById('password').click()
            .clearValue()
            .type(password)
            .end()
            .findById('login').click()
            .end()
    }

};
return loginPage;
});
```

hello.html:

```
<html>
Hello!

<form>
  Email:<input id="email" type='text' name="email"><br>
  Password: <input id="password" type='text' name="password"><br>
  <input id="login" type="submit" value="Log in">
</form>    

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I used fat arrow functions in ES6 (typescript) to get the same effect with less typing.

```
  return this.remote
        .then( () => { login(this.remote, 'admin', 'password'); })
```